# Multiple Statements for question mark operator

Tags: c++

I have two variables

```
int a, b ;
```

`a` and `b` can have any of the values from `0`-`3` and there should be a couple of sentences for each condition based on values of a and b.

I used nested switches:

```
switch(a)
{
    case go:
    {
        switch(b)
        {
            case go: {...}
            ...
            case write: {...}
        }
    }
    ...
    case 3:
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also I have an

```
enum

{
go = 0 ;
wait =1 ;
read = 2;
write =3 ;
}
```

I have a very big nested switch to check all the 4*4 =16 conditions

I would like to implement using  question mark `? :` operator

something like
`(a=b==0) ? Do something ? Do something.`

However I have multiple statements to do in each condition.

How do I do this using this ? : ternary operator?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can your problem not be solved with `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: My problem got solved with Switches itself. but i would like to make my code concise and readable, also want to learn using question mark check.

Comment: Your switch block shown is nonsensical, and what do you mean by `a==b =0`?

Comment: switch(((a&3) << 2) | (b & 3))

Comment: Learning aside, you can made your code concise and readable with `if` and `else` blocks, which are equivalent to the ternary operator. Arguably more so, as `if` and `else` are natural language words, and familiar to a larger audience than the ternary operator.

Comment: @JBentley It depends on what is in the blocks.  In this case, he should probably be using a `switch`, but in a lot of cases, the ternary operator makes the code considerably more readable.

Comment: @James Yes, but the ternary operator is more restricted on what you can do with it, and the OP is facing one of those restrictions.

Comment: I am facing restrictions in using multiple statements for ternary operator

Comment: @user2746930 Which suggests that you might be in a case where the ternary operator isn't appropriate.  (Or that you're trying to do too much in one function.)  Whether the ternary operator is appropriate, or `if/else` or a switch are to be preferred, depends on what you're doing.  The ternary operator is an _expression_, and will generally only be appropriate in contexts where you need an expression, not in contexts where you need a statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might instead want to consider flattening your 4 x 4 switch blocks into a single 16 way switch:

```
#define SELECT(a, b) ((a) * 4 + (b))

int select = SELECT(a, b);

assert(a >= 0 && a < 4);  // sanity checking - make sure a and b are valid
assert(b >= 0 && b < 4);

switch (select)
{
case SELECT(0, 0): 
    // ...
    break;
case SELECT(0, 1): 
    // ...
    break;
case SELECT(0, 2): 
    // ...
    break;
case SELECT(0, 3): 
    // ...
    break;
case SELECT(1, 0): 
    // ...
    break;

// ...

case SELECT(3, 3): 
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Note that this works OK in both C and C++. It also works regardless of whether `a` and `b` are `int`s or `enum`s (note that you can use actual enum labels in the SELECT macro - you don't need to use literal constants).

Comment: Thank you .But I how do I play around this problem using ternary operator ?

Comment: @user2746930 the proper answer for you is: don't use ternary operator.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: good point - I was taking the OP at his word, and assuming that the values of `a` and `b` are always valid, but you could always do range checking beforehand - I'll add a couple of `assert`s for good measure.

Comment: By why do this, rather than his original solution with a nested `switch` (other than obfuscation, of course)?

Comment: @JamesKanze: because 4 x 4 nested switch statements gets very spaghetti-like and difficult to read - flattening it makes it more readable (IMNVHO).

Comment: @SigTerm Easier to read?  When the case label is a complicated expression with no immediate relationship with what it does?  The nested switches are significantly more readable (especially as it is hard to imagine a case where the nested switches wouldn't be refactored out into a separate function).

Comment: The code looks great , but I have one more issue.I have enum values for all the 4 numbers as enum { go = 0 , wait = 1, read = 2 , write =3 ), I cant use these enum values if I follow the above code in case statements like case go :etc

Comment: @user2746930: OK - you didn't mention this in the question - also you've tagged this as both `C` and `C++` - the solution to the enum problem will depend on which language you're actually using?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think I know better than you what is easer to read for me, you know. I would prefer single switch instead of nested switches. Although I'd try to eleminate switch/case or any alternative nested/repeating control structures first.

Comment: @SigTerm It's not a question of opinion, although now that you've added the SELECT macro, you've solved the major objection: your cases are no longer obscure expressions that have to be decyphered.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "It's not a question of opinion" It is. "you've added the SELECT" You've confused me with somebody else.